# MQ error queue manager error logs showing "The error code returned was '701'." MQ errors on MQ V9.2.0.0

Tags: ibm-mq

One of the MQ queue manager is having below errors in it's error logs and due to which SSL channel is in retrying state. Can anyone know about such kind of error.

```
An error indicating a software problem was returned from a function which is
used to provide SSL or TLS support. The error code returned was '701'. The
function call was 'ccigsk_attrib_set_enum - GSK_TRUNCATE_PEER_CERTCHAIN'.

The channel is XXX; in some cases its name cannot be
determined and so is shown as '????'. The channel did not start.
```

Comment: 701 means the attribute was invalid. This sounds like a coding defect in IBM MQ. You should open a case with IBM.

Comment: Make sure you capture a trace while the problem is occurring before you try any restart of the queue manager.   The trace will be key in helping IBM find the cause of the problem.   `strmqtrc -m QMGRNAME -t all -t detail` reproduce the problem and then end it with `endmqtrc -a`.  You can send this to IBM when you open a case.

Comment: Thanks Morag Hughson and JoshMc..Will reach out to IBM.